# x64dbg - see the current position?

Tags: x64dbg

i.e. when the program is running, and x64dbg is attached to the process - how can i see where it is at this moment?
[image]

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly but as you haven't marked mrexodia's answer as the correct one I was wondering if you mean on how to set the view to where the current thread execution is. You can do so by double clicking the RIP register.

Comment: @MichaelPittino this question was a while ago, but now i can't understand well, why i've marked that answer. I really want to know where the current application execution/thread is at this moment

Comment: In CPU view right click -> go to -> origin

Answer (score 4):

From your screenshot I understand that you want to break on. You can do this by breaking on the debug string event. Use the following setting:

[image: setting]

If you want to pause the execution, simply click the “pause” button. If you want to see the current instruction executes you can use the “Threads” tab and double click the EIP/RIP column of one you’re interested in.

Comment: can you remind me where is the `RIP` column?

Comment: The column with the name RIP or EIP (depending on what architecture you’re debugging)

Comment: yes, i  see the `EIP` . thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (go to expression) and type `eip` or `rip` depending on your architecture.

[image]